# Split a string in gnu make with a separator

Tags: makefile, gnu

I have makefile with below code:

```
 .PHONY: $(PROJECTDIR)/projectroot
 $(PROJECTDIR)/projectroot:
if [ -f $(@)/etc/release ]; then \
         #$(RELEASE_VERSION) will have value something like 00.01.02.03
     IFS=. read major minor micro build <<<"${RELEASE_VERSION}" \
         echo major=${major} > $(@)/etc/release \
         echo major=${minor} >> $(@)/etc/release; \
         echo major=${micro} >> $(@)/etc/release; \
         echo major=${build} >> $(@)/etc/release; \
fi
```

I am expecting the $(@)/etc/release to get content like below:

```
 major=00
 minor=01
 micro=02
 build=03
```

I need to replace IFS=. with some equivalent command in gnu make, can you please help me with this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.PHONY: $(PROJECTDIR)/projectroot
$(PROJECTDIR)/projectroot: $(PROJECTDIR)/projectroot/etc/release
$(PROJECTDIR)/projectroot/etc/release:
    echo "${RELEASE_VERSION}" | \
    sed 's/^/major=/; s/\./\nminor=/; s/\./\nmicro=/; s/\./\nbuild=/' >$@
```

Add dependencies to the release file.

Comment: This will create the `etc/release` file if it doesn't exist, which is not what the original does (although the original might not be doing what's wanted, of course)

Comment: Right, but the `if [ -f ${@}/etc/release ]` presumably served _some_ purpose, although I don't know what!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're readin the values into shell variables called `major`, `minor` etc. but then you are printing Make variables with the same names. The shell cannot set the Make variables.

To fix your existing code you need to repeat the `$` characters as `$$` so Make outputs a `$` to the shell, which will interpret them (also you're saying "major" every time, and are missing some semi-colons):

```
     IFS=. read major minor micro build <<<"${RELEASE_VERSION}" ; \
     echo major=$${major} > $(@)/etc/release ;\
     echo minor=$${minor} >> $(@)/etc/release; \
     echo micro=$${micro} >> $(@)/etc/release; \
     echo build=$${build} >> $(@)/etc/release; \
```

But to do it within make you can use the [`subst` and `word`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions) functions:

```
REL_WORDS := $(subst ., ,${RELEASE_VERSION})
...
     echo major=$(word 1,${REL_WORDS}) >  $(@)/etc/release ;\
     echo minor=$(word 2,${REL_WORDS}) >> $(@)/etc/release ;\
     echo micro=$(word 3,${REL_WORDS}) >> $(@)/etc/release ;\
     echo build=$(word 4,${REL_WORDS}) >> $(@)/etc/release ;\
```